# Check if user already bought item in Unity with google play in app purchases

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I'm making an android game with in app purchases and I made a non-consumable item to remove ads. How can I check if the user bought it so I can disable the ads every time the app is launched? I'm using unity IAPs with Google Billing Library.